# Is it worth while creating a custom annotation to show that a method is simply helping readability?

Tags: java, annotations, readability, magic-numbers

Currently working with Spring and I've been learning about methods I can use to help the readability of my code, with one example being replace complicated conditionals with an easy to understand method call. For example:

```
private void myMethod(){
    //Bad
    if(userAge < MIN_AGE){
        //logic
    }

    //Good
    if(userTooYoung()){
        //logic
    }
}

private boolean userTooYoung(){
    return userAge < MIN_AGE;
}
```

My question is: is it worth while creating a custom annotation to show that userTooYoung is simply there to help the readability? For example:

```
@Assistant
private boolean userTooYoung(){
    return userAge < MIN_AGE;
}
```

I can't really think of another function the @Assistant annotation could serve, thus, it begs the question of is it really worth it?

EDIT: 
I've been playing around with the idea of an @Assistant annotation and come up with the following:

Definition:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Assistant {

    enum With {
        CONDITIONAL_LOGIC, CONSTRUCTION_LOGIC
    }

    With help() default With.CONDITIONAL_LOGIC;
}
```

Usage:

```
@Assistant(help = Assistant.With.CONDITIONAL_LOGIC)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this annotation madness is getting out of hand.

Comment: And so is 'readability'. I don't see any difference between `userTooYoung()` and `userAge < MIN_AGE`, and in most cases I would opt for the solution with the least lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for an opinion. To a point, I agree with tsolakp; too many annotations with vague names *decreases* readability. At the same time, a custom annotation that is simply used for readability does make sense if you need to mark something you do in a number of places and what you are doing isn't obvious. For example, Google Guava provides the @VisibleForTesting annotation. It is used when what should be a private method is made default scope so it can be unit tested. I use it quite a bit when a client requires thorough unit tests.

As far as your case, it's not adding any clarity, and the name isn't very meaningful.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "For example, a marker annotation where you make what would be a private method default scope for unit testing makes sense." please?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** not everything you can do should be done

I definitely don't think it is worth to do so, to be honest you should not do so:

- From clean code perspective you add more clutter without any additional information.
- What is the difference to a comment here and would you write that comment? No
- Mostly any private method is just to improve readability which is fine. Why you need to add this implicit info in an explicit way?

Comment: I've edited my question with a better example. However, your points are really good and it seems to be that having an annotation is trying to make a shortcut by taking the long way, i.e. if need be, comments could be added.

Comment: The only advantage I see is the option to do an automatic analysis on methods annotated in such a way. But who wants to know how many conditional helper methods you have in your code?